# How to select all records referenced by a specified set of other records

Tags: sql, many-to-many

I have two tables with a many-to-many association. I'd like to be able to run a single, parameterized, query that returns all rows on one side that is referenced by a specified set (of arbitrary size) of records in the other table.

To illustrate the problem, consider the case (comparable to my own) where the tables are:

1. Movie
2. Actor
3. Movie_Actor *linking table*

It is fairly trivial to write a query to return all movies that a given actor is in, or even any specific number of actors have co-starred in, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM Movie
WHERE Movie.ID IN (
  SELECT Movie_Actor.Movie_ID FROM Movie_Actor
  WHERE Movie_Actor.Actor_ID = ?
  )
```

Then you can use INTERSECT or multiple statements in the WHERE clause to narrow it further. But these approaches all, as far as I can tell, rely on a predetermined, fixed number of conditionals in the query. Sure, you could assemble such a query in code, but that defeats my purpose. I just want a single query that I can stick the parameters in.

And if I do `WHERE Movie_Actor.Actor_ID IN ?` then of course I just get a list of all movies any actor in the list has been in.

I can't see how I could query to get a list of all movies that a **set** of actors have been in, where that set is larger than 0, but its size is otherwise unconstrained.

Is there a way to construct such a query that would accept a set of *actor_id*s as parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use multiple `exists` conditions:

```
select m.*
from movie m
where 
    exists (select 1 from movie_actor mv where mv.movie_id = m.id and mv.actor_id = ?)
    and exists (select 1 from movie_actor mv where mv.movie_id = m.id and mv.actor_id = ?)
    and ...
```

That should be a rather efficent approach.

On the other hand, you can use aggregation - which is shorter to write, but might be a bit slower (depending on your dataset), and requires you to enumerate the columns to keep in `movie`:

```
select m.id, m.name
from movie m
inner join movie_actor mv 
    on  mv.movie_id = m.id 
    and mv.actor_id in (?, ?)  -- either one actor or the other
group by m.id, m.name
having count(*) = 2            -- both matched
```

Comment: I've clarified in my question that I'm looking for a query that I can simple plug the parameters into. That rules about the 'exists' approach. Your second approach requires passing in the size of the set as a parameter, but that is very doable and I wound up using that approach. Much obliged.